# How to fix problem with _construct function after Route Model Binding?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

After setting up a controller and a view to show a specific entry from my database, I wanted to use laravels function of Route Model Binding to fetch the data fromn the database and pass it to the view. However I am getting following error:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError thrown with
>   message "Argument 2 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must
>   be of the type integer, array given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\Cyberchess\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php
>   on line 203"

I've tried to add this line to TrustProxy:

```
protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;
```

as the internet recommended, but when I opened the file, I realised it was already in the code.
My create/store works properly, which is why I assume it has something to do with Route Model Binding. I'm currently using a getRouteKeyName() to change the Key to 'AccID' so it should work.

```php
//my controller
public function show(account $account){

        //$account = account::where(['AccID' => $account])->get();
        //dd($account);

        return redirect('user.show', compact('account'));

    }
//my model
class account extends Model
{
    public function getRouteKeyName() {
        return 'AccID';
    }
    public $timestamps = false;


}
//my view
<h1 class="title">Your Profile</h1>
<p>{{ $account->Nick }}</p>
```

I expected it to work just fine(duh), but got said error. When I dd(); the data, it has the information I want inside #attributes and in #original.
If if comment the dd() and let the return do it's work, I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect()` helper function is used to send a redirect 301 response from the server, what you want instead is to return a `view` like so

```php
public function show(account $account)
{
   $account = account::where(['AccID' => $account])->get();
   return view('user.show', compact('account'));

}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you.
Also: You don't need the whole $account = line to get it to work.